# Como alterar .htaccess do Wordpress via FTP

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Preciso fazer alterações no .htacces do meu wordpress, mas acho que o arquivo que eu encontrei não é o correto.
Alguém sabe onde fica o .htaccess que alteram as páginas do wordpress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress gera o .htaccess na root do seu site. Além disso, pode haver outros .htaccess em subpastas. O arquivo mais próximo ao URL solicitado é aplicado primeiro.

O ponto antes do nome do arquivo indica que ele é um arquivo oculto. Quando você está acessando seu servidor web através de FTP, você não será capaz de ver o .htaccess, a menos que o seu cliente FTP é forçado a mostrar arquivos ocultos.

[image: Filezilla: menú Server - Show hidden files]